# What kind of code does tkinter's mainloop collect?

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose I have Python code like this

```
# <Pure Python statement A>
root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
# <Pure Python statement B>
# <other tkinter code>
root.mainloop()
```

Which statements are then ending up on tkinter's mainloop? Is it just the 3 tkinter statements?

**EDIT**

There must be more things going on, because some code between the tkinter code is affected: When I run the following code (taken from another question)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

filename = ""

def op():
    global filename
    filename =tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()

root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Button(mainframe, text="Open file", command=op).grid(column=0, row=1)
root.mainloop()
print(filename)
```

after closing the program the selected filename is displayed. But when running

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

filename = "this_is_a_test"

def op():
    global filename
    filename =tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()

root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Button(mainframe, text="Open file", command=op).grid(column=0, row=1)
print(filename)
root.mainloop()
```

after closing the program, nothing is displayed. So somehow the pure Python statements before `mainloop` seem to get absorbed.

Comment: I don't think Python contains enough magic to allow a method call to grab arbitrary code that came before it. I don't have experience with Tkinter, but that would be very odd and surprising.

Comment: Why the downvotes? A beginner is here, trying to wrap his head around event-driven programming.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I had to guess, it's because you seem to be making odd guesses regarding how things work. Why do you believe that `mainloop` "collects" code that came before it? Downvotes can indicate that a question isn't helpful, and I can't see this being helpful to future users. A better question would be how to have code run in the main loop, but I suspect that's already answered in Tkinter's documentation.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm making uninformed guesses, since I did not find any tutorials online, that explained this well.

Comment: Again, try the documentation for Tkinter. Considering I'm pretty sure it's geared towards beginners, the documentation should be thorough.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The documentation does not contain such explanations. And my guesses are based on examples, see my edit.

Comment: Something else is going on, and that would be a good question. As I said above though, a method call can't simply absorb other code that came before it. I think you're attributing something to magic when there's likely a much simpler explanation. Is this the exact code that you ran? The simple explanation would be that `filename` is actually an empty string originally, so it won't be visible when printed before `op` runs.

Comment: I think you just forgot to change `filename` between tests. That explains everything.

Comment: Replace `print(filename)` with `print(repr(filename))` to see even the emptyness of `filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of code does tkinter's mainloop collect?

It doesn't collect anything. It simply processes events, and calls functions bound to those events. It also calls functions added to the queue via `after`.

> Which statements are then ending up on tkinter's mainloop? Is it just the 3 tkinter statements?

Nothing "ends up on tkinter's mainloop". That's a nonsensical statement, nothing can end up on it. It is just a function that processes events, and doesn't return until the window is destroyed. All code before the call to `mainloop` executes according to the normal rules of python.

Calling mainloop is effectively the same as if you put this in its place (but it is much more efficient):

```
while True:
    self.update()
```

Much like with the above, any code after `mainloop()` will not execute until the loop exits, which happens when the window has been destroyed.

The reason your print seems to work after the call to `mainloop` but not before is simply that before `mainloop`, `filename` is the empty string. The `print` run normally, it's just that there's nothing to print. That `print` statement happens a few milliseconds after the program starts, way before the user has a chance to do anything. When called after, it seems to work because that code doesn't run until the window has been destroyed. At that point it presumably has a value, so you see something printed.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: There's *no* kind of code that mainloop collects.

---

It '*collect*' s all configuration that is related to the Tcl interpreter it is a method of. As in if your GUI is a configuration of `root = tk.Tk()`, and the `mainloop` is a method of `root` then all configurations under it will be accounted for such as children widgets and their configurations.

---

Your `print` statement doesn't get absorbed. It simply prints what would've been printed if the button was never used. Try the 2nd code with simply closing the GUI *without* using the button. `mainloop` doesn't absorb *anything*. It simply waits for events for the GUI configured.

Comment: That sounds as if I can basically place arbitrary code between the lines of the Tk code, because the `mainloop` just pertains to those lines anyway. But the edit to my question shows that that can't be the case.